# Installing WiFi drivers for 14e4:43a0 rev 3 broadcom pcie device - can't find bcmwl-kernel-source package

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, broadcom

I have a new Kali Rolling set up and am having numerous problems attempting to install WiFi drivers for a broadcom 14e4:43a0 device (TP LINK Archer T8E). I am currently USB tethering from my phone.

Searching online gave me results that I should install the bcmwl-kernel-source package for the drivers but whenever I attempt to apt-get bcmwl-kernel-source I get `E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source`.

I have tried to download this package straight from the web and installing from a local folder but still get the same error.

I then proceeded to continue to search for solutions, many to do with updating the `/etc/apt/sources.list` list. I have tried messing with those with no prevail and have since defaulted those changes back.

It seems every package that I try to install (can install but) doesn't help me setting up WiFi.

No WLAN devices show up in `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`.

Using `modprobe wl` returns a fatal error, something about `wl` not being found (currently not at work to access machine).

Any further help, ideas and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Searching online gave me results that I should install the bcmwl-kernel-source package for the drivers" Could you link to the page where it says that, please?

Comment: The first hit I get is https://wiki.debian.org/wl. Did you try those instructions? The Debian Wiki isn't perfect, but the instructions are usually relatively reliable.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it is the correct way to install the BCM4360 driver .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bcmwl-kernel-source` isn't available on kali repository the alternative package is the [`broadcom-sta-dkms`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/broadcom-sta)

with the regularly [kali-linux repository](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories), your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain only this URL:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

the `apt-cache search broadcom-sta` will show you:

```
broadcom-sta-common - Common files for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
broadcom-sta-dkms - dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
broadcom-sta-source - Source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
```

To install the driver for the `BCM4360` (`14e4:43a0`) wireless card run the following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot and install the `linux-headers` package (run `apt-cache search linux-headers` to get the available `linux-headers`) then run:

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

Comment: thanks @GAD3R this solution work for me Installing Broadcom 4360 Kali Linux on MacBook Air, use Wireless External adapter first to get internet connection then, do above solution, and now you are ready to connect to internet without External Adapter.